# Swagger delivers different source codes in Hub and Editor

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-editor

There is the Swagger Editor (https://editor.swagger.io/) and Swagger Hub (https://swaggerhub.com/). I thought both are doing the same job, untill I noticed, that the source codes are different.
Im my case, I generated a nodejs server in both and looked at the sourcecode.

Swagger editor delivers:

```
exports.getJobs = function(args, res, next) {
  /**
   * Returns all jobs
   *
   * page String page (optional)
   * returns List
   **/
  var examples = {};
  examples['application/json'] = [ {
      // my json
} ];
  if (Object.keys(examples).length > 0) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.end(JSON.stringify(examples[Object.keys(examples)[0]] || {}, null, 2));
  } else {
    res.end();
  }
}
```

whereas Swagger Hub delivers:

```
/**
 * Returns all jobs
 *
 * page String page (optional)
 * returns List
 **/
exports.getJobs = function(page) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var examples = {};
    examples['application/json'] = [ {
            // my json
} ];
    if (Object.keys(examples).length > 0) {
      resolve(examples[Object.keys(examples)[0]]);
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  });
}
```

Why are the function parameters different? In Swagger Online editor it's

```
exports.getJobs = function(args, res, next)
```

and in Swagger Hub Editor it's

```
exports.getJobs = function(page)
```

but why? Which is the right one to use? How can I use the parameter res (eg to set the header) in swagger hub if it's not passed?

Answer (score 0):

Code generation is powered by [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen). Apparently, Swagger Editor and SwaggerHub use different versions of the codegen. There's no "right" codegen, there're just older and newer versions. You can reach out to the Editor developers and SwaggerHub developers to learn which versions of the codegen each tool uses.

To get consistent results, you can download the [CLI version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-codegen-cli) of the codegen and run it yourself:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.3.jar generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.yaml -l nodejs-server -o Petstore
```